# Nivoslider: change width and height of slider afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, typo3, nivo-slider

I'm developing a mobile version of a TYPO3 site. There I use the plugin `nivoslider` which uses the official known Nivo Slider. Now I have to reduce the size of the slider. How can I reach this?

In TYPO3 there is a setting on the plugin page with width and height but this would affect also the full size website. Because there is no manual I don't think I can use Typoscript to set the width and the height afterwards.

I tried to set the width with CSS

```
.nivoSlider {
    width: 300px !important;
    height: auto !important;
}

.nivoSlider img {
    width: 300px !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

but when the slider is loaded it uses the normal size of the pictures. Only the slider container itself is cropping the images but it has a wrong height (only dots and a small part of the image can be seen).

I also tried to look into the documentation to see if I could set the width and the height somehow. But I didn't found any settings. Are there any javascript/jquery solutions I could use? This doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.nivoslider img').each(function(index, element){
    alert('test');
    $(this).width(300);
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    src = 'fileadmin/templates/timthumb/timthumb.php?src=' + src + '&w=300';
    $(this).attr("src", src);
  });
});
```

It seems that `.nivoslider` is built afterwards, but my code is executed before. This is the confirmation:

```
  if ($('.nivoslider').length != 0) {
    alert('element found');
  }else{
    alert('element NOT found');
  }
```

The code above gives me `element NOT found`, because the initialisation of extension is at the end of the `header` and my code is before. How can I include Javascript code at the end of the header in TYPO3?

Now I think I will use this CSS, because I don't see any solution:

`.nivoslider {
    display: none;
}`

Comment: Your going to need to at least get rid of the dimenion attributes the script puts on the images.

Comment: The problem is that my function is never called. So I can't remove anything ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take a look at this...

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/2012/05/30/the-nivo-slider-is-responsive/

**########################## UPDATE #############################**

The above link has been removed, please see the following for example:

http://www.flynsarmy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/nivoslider/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried to exchange the `nivo-slider.css` and `jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js`, but I don't think it is that simple. Now I don't see any buttons (next, prev, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..) and the slider is not responsive. I also tried to delete width and height attributes (manually in Firebug) but the slider is still not responsive. For the theme I would need a `div` container around the slider, but with the extension I use this is hard to get. I would have to update the extension myself ... Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: If the slider is just for this website you could probably not go wrong by just directly making changes in the plugin.

Comment: Now I tried what you said. It seems to work except a few things. In FF with iPhone as user agent it is cropping the image (if you resize the window than it is OK, but only for this picture - not the next one). In IE7 the dots at the bottom are missing. On my iPhone it seems to work, but the transition is not as nice as in the desktop version.

Comment: Glad your nearly there. Not sure about FF but IE7 pager is probably going to be a z-index/positioning issue.

Comment: You are right. Currently IE7 users have bad luck, but I have no time for searching the css issue now ...

Comment: Wouldnt worry about it anyway, IE7 not even on that stats anymore. http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201110-201210

Comment: Thanks for the link. Nice to have such an overview ;)

Comment: @Alex This link does not exist now.Can u pls update your answer

Answer (score 0):

change height by changing the height in the img tag in the html file and change width by changing the width in .slider-wrapper in style.css.